# Trying to define Dedekind-Hasse norm in a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

I have the following definition:

> Let D be an integral domain; a function $N:D \to \mathbb{N}$ is a $\textbf{Dedekind-Hasse}$ norm if  $$\forall  0 \neq a,b \in D;\quad b|a \quad \lor \quad \exists s,t \in D: 0 < N(sa-tb)<N(b)$$

If we have  D a PID, could we simply define:

> $$N:D \to \mathbb{N}  \\ \quad \quad \quad \quad x \to 1; x=0 \\
> \quad \quad \quad \quad x \to 2; x \neq 0$$

If $a,b \in D - \{0\}$ and b|a, we're done, otherwise as $Da+Db$ is also an ideal, so $0=sa-tb$ for some $s,t \in D $ and $0 < N(sa-tb)<N(b)$. Is this a valid example and if so, is it of any use?